# Reading CSV in R with zoo

Tags: r, csv, xts, zoo

I have a CSV in the following format:

```
TICKER,PER,DATE,TIME,CLOSE
SYMBOL,1,20160104,1002,14180.0000000
SYMBOL,1,20160104,1003,14241.0000000
```

I would like to read it into a time series:

```
f <- function(a, b) {
    c <- paste(a, b)
    return(strptime(c, format = "%Y%m%d %H%M"))
}
d <- read.zoo("test.csv", FUN = f, index.column = list("DATE", "TIME"))
```

And what I get is `index does not match data`. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading csv with date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372211/reading-csv-with-date-and-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `header = TRUE` and `sep = ","`, since they are not the defaults for `read.zoo` like they are for `read.csv`.

```
d <- read.zoo(text="TICKER,PER,DATE,TIME,CLOSE
SYMBOL,1,20160104,1002,14180.0000000
SYMBOL,1,20160104,1003,14241.0000000",
  FUN = f, index.column = list("DATE", "TIME"),
  header=TRUE, sep=",")
d
#                     TICKER PER CLOSE
# 2016-01-04 10:02:00 SYMBOL 1   14180
# 2016-01-04 10:03:00 SYMBOL 1   14241
```

Comment: Note that the data part of this is a character matrix which is unlikely what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Character and numeric columns can't both be part of the time series data because the data portion of a zoo object is a matrix (and a matrix must be all numeric, all character or all other type); however, one can split to wide form on the character column using `split=`  Also we can avoid having to specify function `f` by specifying `format=` and `tz=`.  Further, we must specify that a header is present (`header=`) and that fields are separated with the "," character (`sep=`).

(Below we have used `text = Lines` for reproducibliity but in reality replace that with `"test.csv"`.)

```
Lines <- "TICKER,PER,DATE,TIME,CLOSE
SYMBOL,1,20160104,1002,14180.0000000
SYMBOL,1,20160104,1003,14241.0000000"

library(zoo)

read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", index = c("DATE", "TIME"), 
  split = "TICKER", format = "%Y%m%d %H%M", tz = "")
```

giving:

```
                    PER CLOSE
2016-01-04 10:02:00   1 14180
2016-01-04 10:03:00   1 14241
```

**Note:** If you do want to use your function `f` anyways then omit `format` and `tz` and use:

```
read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", index = c("DATE", "TIME"), 
  split = "TICKER", FUN = f)
```

This would also work, i.e. read it into a data frame and then read the data frame into a zoo object:

```
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines) # read.csv defaults to header=TRUE, sep=","
read.zoo(DF, index = c("DATE", "TIME"), split = "TICKER", FUN = f)
```